# Chromedriver with webdriverio - unhandled request on init

Tags: webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver-io

I'm trying to run ChromeDriver and test against it with a cucumber setup, it's a very basic google search test, but when I run the test it comes back with:

```
(::) failed steps (::)

RuntimeError: RuntimeError
     Problem: unhandled request

     Callstack:
     -> init()
```

I'm running chromedriver with:

```
>chromedriver --url-base=wd/hub/session
Starting ChromeDriver (v2.10.267521) on port 9515
Only local connections are allowed.
```

And the world.js file that is running from cucumber is:

```
var prefix = 'capabilities:';
var capabilities = {};
var World = function (callback) {
    this.webdriverio    = require('webdriverio');
    this.browser = this.webdriverio
    .remote({'port':9515, 'desiredCapabilities': capabilities})
    .init();

    callback();
};
exports.World = World;
```

I've done a test with a selenium jar instead of chromedriver, and that works, but testing eventually needs to be done primarily against a CEF client, and we would need to get chromedriver working.

Comment: Have you tried to add `browserName: 'chrome'` to the capabilities object? If no capabilities are given WebdriverIO takes firefox as default browser

Answer (score 3):

My script to start selenium with chromedriver

```
#!/bin/bash
java -jar /var/lib/selenium/selenium-server.jar -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=/var/lib/chrome-driver/chromedriver
```

Comment: As of v3 any parameters need to be declared before the -jar parameter. See https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/2566 for more information